# Valores faltantes en resultado de consulta

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, join

Primeramente tengo una relacion muchos a muchos, están son las tablas: providers, products y product_provider.

```
 Schema::create('providers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name',45)->require()->unique();
        $table->string('slug')->require()->unique();
        $table->string('rif',45);
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


  Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


 Schema::create('product_provider', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('provider_id');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->string('trademark');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
```

yo necesito consultar registros en la tabla pivote, entonces accedo a la tabla pivote y a sus relaciones de la siguiente manera:

```
  $pedidos = DB::table('product_provider')
  ->join('providers','providers.id','provider_id')
  ->join('products','products.id','product_id')
  ->whereIn('product_provider.id',$this->pivotsId)->get();
```

El problema esta en que $pedidos contiene todos los datos de la relacion excepto el "name" ni el "slug" de la tabla providers , solo me muestra el name y slug de la tabla products

[image: dd($pedidos)]

Mi teoria es que como las columnas "name" y "slug" son iguales en ambas tablas al hacer la consulta solo me trae los de una sola tabla, Porque creo esto? porque yo intercambie el orden de los join() en la consulta que realice y  me mostro los datos de la tabla providers completa pero esta vez falto el name y slug de la tabla products.

ahora bien que debo hacer? es la única solución cambiar nombres  de mis columnas de base de datos por nameProduct slugProduct nameProvider slugProvider para que no genere conflicto ? habrá otra forma de solucionar esto? .

Comment: Gracias @BetaM me funciono tu respuesta,  colocar  alias a las columnas iguales para que  no entraran en conflicto.

Comment: Esta pregunta no es sobre sql, ni join, ni base de datos.. es sobre laravel (o algo asi).. no?

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionar el problema colocando en la consulta la clausula select() y definiendo un alias a las columnas que tengan el mismo nombre.

```
select('products.name as product', 'providers.name as provider')
```